# fortran split data in many files and do some processing

Tags: split, fortran

I want to split my text file and save it in many files and perform some calculation for every file and get results. 
I wrote this code but it does code just in one file. 
I glad somebody help me.

```
rogram split
  implicit none
  integer:: n1,i,k,j
  parameter (n1=52017)
  real*8::bjd1,bjd(n1),phase(n1),flux(n1),errflux(n1),bjd2,sumation,ave
  open (1,file="myfile.txt")
  do i=1,n1
            read(1,*)  bjd(i),phase(i),flux(i),errflux(i)
            enddo
    close(1)
 bjd1=(bjd(1)+4)
 bjd2=bjd(1)
 j=0

 do k=1,n1
    if (bjd(k).le.bjd1) then
        write(2,*) bjd(k),phase(k),flux(k),errflux(k)
        j=j+1
        else
             write(2,*)'solution'
             bjd1=bjd(k)+4
             sumation=bjd2+bjd(k-1)
             ave=sumation/2
             bjd2=bjd(j)
             write(3,*)j,ave
     end if
 end do
end program
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to **strongly** discourage you from using unit numbers less than 10. Depending on your compiler and system, some of these numbers are used for stdin, stdout, and errout.

What I'd do is to declare an integer variable, for example `out_unit`, and then use that in this way:

```
integer :: out_unit
...
open(newunit=out_unit, file=...)
...
write(out_unit, *) vars
...
close(out_unit)
```

If you want to cycle between output files, why not use something like this:

```
integer :: out_unit
...
open(newunit=out_unit, file=<first file>, ...)
do ...
    ...
    write(out_unit, ...) ...
    if (<cycle trigger>) then
        close(out_unit)
        open(newunit=out_unit, file=...)
    end if
    ...
end do
...
close(out_unit)
```

**Edited to add**

As @s8129 pointed out, the `newunit` parameter is fairly recent, and while *most* Fortran compilers now understand it, not all do. If yours doesn't, you can do it the 'old-fashioned way':

```
integer, parameter :: out_unit = 101   ! Some unique number >10
```

And then replace every `newunit=out_unit` in the `open` statements with `unit=out_unit`

Comment: Might be worth noting that `newunit` is a new Fortran 2008 specifier. While it would be nice to all have access to new compilers, I've seen plenty of IT systems where this is certainly not the case

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've taken it on board.

Comment: thank you for your helping,i am  beginner in fortran but I am trying to improve my code upon on your answering. thank you again

Comment: I need more help,i  want to split one txt file and build more than 300 txt files this is upon simple addition on first data in first column of my txt file  and do some of calculation on every file means I want to have loop in write (),how can solve it? thank you

Comment: I wrote this code but it repeat in every txt file same data and don't do what I want. 

     do i=1,n1
                read(1,*)  bjd(i),phase(i),flux(i),errflux(i)
                enddo
        close(1)
do p=2,3
 write(myfilename,100) p
 100 format('file_',i3.3,'.txt')
 x=54957.539199999999
 do k=1,n1
    open (p,file=myfilename)
    if (bjd(k).le.x) then
        j=j+1
            write(p,*) bjd(k),phase(k),flux(k),errflux(k)
            else
                close(p)
                x=(bjd(k)+4)
                end if
                end do
end do
end program

Answer (score 0):

```
I can write this code and get my results
enter code here`
    j=1
       close(1)
         x=bjd(1)+0.25
        n=11
    write(myfilename,"(a,i0,a)") "myfilename",n,".txt"
 open (n,file=myfilename)
 do k=j,50
   print*,x,j,n
    if (bjd(k).le.x) then
        print*,bjd(k)
       write(n,*) bjd(k),phase(k),flux(k),errflux(k)
           j=j+1
           else
            close(n)
           n=n+1
           x=(bjd(j)+0.25)
             end if
 end do
end program
```